# Where is this grey camera shape coming from?

Tags: camera

I can't seem to delete this camera shape as I don't know where it's coming from. I don't have any cameras in my scene, nothing in the shader and compositor. The shape only appears in the wire and solid mode.

How can I remove this as it's cropping objects outside the shape?

[image: blender view camera shape]

Comment: you've accidentally pressed Alt B for View Clipping Border, press Alt B again: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/navigate/clip.html

Comment: Haha thanks so much @moonboots, that did it!

Comment: That's exactly right @lemon! Thanks for sharing this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accidentally selected `Alt` + `B`. Selecting `Alt` + `B` again did the trick.